# How do I fix 'The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect' when trying to start environment

Tags: node.js, wordpress, docker-compose, wordpress-gutenberg, npm-run

I have currently forked and cloned this [repo](https://github.com/lesore0789/gutenberg-examples) and followed the instructions on the README.md. I have no problem installing my dependencies, but once I go to the next step of starting the WordPress instance with the `npm run env:start` command, I get this output:

[image: bash output]

I have been trying to trouble-shoot this for a couple of days and have not been able to figure it out.

Can someone please help me with this?

My system is a Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue using npm run with env-cmd. I recalled recently upgrading my npm version. I believe it was 8.13.0. I just downgraded to 8.6.0 and the issue is gone.

If you are using NVM for windows, I recommend this script to install/update/downgrade NPM.

https://gist.github.com/johnmcase/d31b799b9030327091a0e74880e4c530

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I did the same thing. Downgrading npm from 8.13.x to 8.6 and the issue was resolved.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers. Your answer is very similar to the first answer and not very useful since it does not add any new value or information. Please avoid writing duplicate answers. Either edit your answer to add value or delete it altogether; this will ensure all questions and answers on the site remain useful and not scattered/duplicated.